# showing line by line in Multi Line Textbox

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

When I search for phone number, it shows it line by line in `DataGridView`, but in my `TextBox` it shows it one beside one. Do you know why?

```
var con = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");

con.Open();

var cmd = new OleDbCommand
{
    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
    CommandText = "select * from data where [ID] like(" + textBox9.Text + ")",
    Connection = con,
};

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
    textBox20.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();
}

con.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Is `textBox20` then one with three numbers on it? What is the `Description` column in the database? Probably just need to handle new lines (`\r` vs `\r\n`).

Comment: can you please clear your answer ?

Comment: its like that var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox2.Text = reader["Phone number"].ToString();

Comment: you mean to use it here       textBox2.Text = reader["Phone Number"].ToString()+"\r\n";

Comment: I used this also         textBox2.Text = reader["Phone Number"].ToString()  + Environment.NewLine;

Comment: Why did you put C# 2, 3 and 4 in the tags? Choose only the one you're using!